# BUILD FAILED on Android studio with micromata API for KML file

Tags: java, android, kml

i`m having a trouble running my class with micromata API.
I tried to work with this solution-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15638172/5103137

but i`m getting an BUILD FAILED error while

```
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (com/sun/codemodel/CodeWriter) does not match path (1.0/com/sun/codemodel/CodeWriter.class)
```

How can I fix it?